Django oauth toolkit, setting the scopes for separate authorization server
I am trying to separate my resource server with the authorization server https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resource_server.html, and now confused on the setting of the SCOPES available in the authorization server.
From my understanding, the authorization server would need to know the entities/models of the resource server in order for it to be able to create scopes, for example scopes like read:products, delete:products, read:customers, etc. Then the auth server would need to know that products, customers, etc. exist as entities in the resource server. So would my auth server (on startup) need to read the db of the resource server and get all the entities in it, so it can create scopes? How is this usually done in industry? Wouldn't this also mean the auth server is not completely isolated from the resource server?
(since if the resource and auth servers are the same, it's easy to get the models/entities, but now it's confusing).
And if I have the servers separate like this I would have 2 databases (the resource server's and the authorization's). How should I synchronize user related tables between the two databases? Since my resource server still needs user related data too e.g. an attribute User in Product object. I have two auth_user tables now that needs to be in sync; how is this usually done?
